# Android Studio : "cannot find symbol" error after adding dependency

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine

I am using the Unity engine to generate an android studio project.
My main project's main activity has the following code in its NativeActivity class:

```
return mUnityPlayer.injectEvent(event);
```

Everything compiles and works fine.
However, when I add a certain 3rd party library (androidNative) as a module [image: screenshot of adding the dependency]

I get the following error when I try to compile :

```
Error:(86, 89) error: cannot find symbol method injectEvent(MotionEvent)
```

This is surprising, because it is an error in a file from the original project (not the module I added) and I only added a reference.
What is the reason behind this scenario? How can adding a module as a dependency of a project cause a file in the original project to not compile?

Comment: Have you tried restarting Android Studio? I get dependency errors like this pretty often due to IDE bugs

Comment: Tried clean->close->open->build. Didn't help...

Comment: And when you remove the dependency does the error go away?

Comment: Yes, it does. Sadly.

Comment: The proper tag for Uniyt3D is #unity3d as #unity is a different kind of software.

Comment: I have the same problem. Is there a chance that you have discovered a method ? Would be glad, if you shared.